# Filter the products where your calculated options generate a profit result

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I need to filter for each of the products, which are the distances that are profitable using them.

In the example below, using `car` the profitable distance is `3` and `skate` the profitable distances are `3` and `5`:

| product (column A) | distance (column B) | profit/loss (column C) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | 3 | -1 |
| skate | 5 | 1 |
| skate | 7 | 2 |
| car | 7 | -1 |
| skate | 7 | -3 |
| car | 3 | 3 |
| skate | 5 | -4 |
| skate | 5 | 6 |
| skate | 3 | 2 |

So the result I would like to get would be this:

| options (column E) | distances (column F) |
| --- | --- |
| car | 3 |
| skate | 3,5 |

Column E:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A)
```

Column F:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E1:E="","",JOIN(",",FILTER(UNIQUE(B1:B),SUMIFS(C1:C,A1:A,E1:E,B1:B,UNIQUE(B1:B))))))
```

I tried to use `FILTER` and combine with `SUMIFS`, but it generated error in divergent size ranges.

I would like to know if there is any way I can make this filter somehow for each of the objects and that I have the freedom to increase the number of products according to the time (that's why I combined it with `ARRAYFORMULA`, so I don't get stuck adding line-by-line formulas)

**Edit 1:**

Why `7` is not included in Profit for `Skate`:

Because at distance `7`, we have the values `2` and `-3`, so it becomes a return `-1`

**Edit 2:**

Why `3,5` in Profit for `Skate`:

Because at distance `3`, we have the value `2`, so it becomes a return `+2`

Because at distance `5`, we have the values `1`, `-4` and `6`, so it becomes a return `+3`

Comment: Explain skate 3,5, and 7 too, you want the avg(B)?

Comment: why skate 7 is not included?

Comment: @player0 Added why 7 is not profitable on skate

Comment: @Osm Added why 3.5 is profitable for skate

Comment: I see now @DigitalFarmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 QUERY({A2:A&"​", B2:B&",", C2:C}, "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) group by Col1,Col2"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col3 >0 group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "​")), ",$", ))
```

[image]